# Smooth structure on $M/G$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

Let $M$ be compact smooth manifold and $G$ -- a group acting freely on $M$. The problem is to prove that there is the smooth structure on $M/G$ which makes the map $\pi: M \to M/G$ smooth.

I know only how to put topology on $M/G$ and have no idea how to define charts.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you additionally need that the action is proper in order to obtain a smooth manifold.

Comment: Yes; consider irrational rotation of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is more or less the following. Take a small open set $U\subset M$, then the tangents to the orbits define a distribution $N\subseteq TU$. You should be able to pick a complement to $N$ in $TU$ (for example fixing a Riemannian metric on $M$ and taking the orthogonal complement with respect to it), and this complement will heuristically be $T(M/G)$. You prove that this complement is an integrable distribution, and then by Frobenius' theorem you can integrate it to a submanifold which is locally like $M/G$, and thus gives you a chart.

---

See e.g. around Definition 2.12 [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292155197_Infinite_Dimensional_Moment_Map_Theory_in_Differential_Geometry) (and the references therein).

Comment: Funny thing is that this problem was given to us after the first lecture on "calculus on manifolds". And though I know a little bit about distributions and so on, all covered in our course by now was just the defenition of manifold.

Comment: So, I am sure if I can use such a things.

Comment: @Vladislav Ok. Then yeah, there must be an easier method.

Comment: @Vladislav Wait a second. When you say "group" do you mean *finite group*, *Lie group*, or just any group? Because my answer is what you need for Lie groups, if $G$ is a finite group then it's much easier.

Comment: @ Daniel Robert-Nicoud, there is nothing said about it...it's written just "a group"

Comment: @Vladislav Then you have a problem. You need at least one additional assumption (e.g. that the action is proper). I think the exercise you are given should read "$G$ a **finite** group."

Comment: @Vladislav See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1777556/60713 (which is exactly what Neal pointed out under your OP).